# ess font-lock-add-keywords not working

Tags: ess, comment

For several years I have been [using this bit of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941429/structuring-a-statistical-analysis-with-r-using-emacs-ess) in my init.el file to organize comments. Here is the code
`

```
(defgroup ess-jb-faces nil
  "Faces used by cutomized ess-mode"
  :group 'faces)

(defface ess-jb-comment-face
  '((t (:background "cornsilk" 
    :foreground "DimGrey"
    :inherit font-lock-comment-face)))
  "Face used to highlight comments."
  :group 'ess-jb-faces)

(defface ess-jb-comment-bold-face
  '((t (:weight bold
    :inherit ess-jb-comment-face)))
  "Face used to highlight bold in comments."
  :group 'ess-jb-faces)

(defface ess-jb-h1-face
  '((t (:height 1.6 
    :weight bold 
    :foreground "MediumBlue"
    :inherit ess-jb-comment-face)))
  "Face used to highlight h1 headers."
  :group 'ess-jb-faces)

(defface ess-jb-h2-face
  '((t (:height 1.2 
    :weight bold 
    :foreground "DarkViolet"
    :inherit ess-jb-comment-face)))
  "Face used to highlight h2 headers."
  :group 'ess-jb-faces)

(defface ess-jb-h3-face
  '((t (:height 1.0 
    :weight bold 
    :foreground "DarkViolet"
    :inherit ess-jb-comment-face)))
  "Face used to highlight h3 headers."
  :group 'ess-jb-faces)

(defface ess-jb-hide-face
  '((t (:foreground "white"
    :background "white"
    :inherit ess-jb-comment-face)))
  "Face used to hide characters."
  :group 'ess-jb-faces)

(font-lock-add-keywords 'ess-mode
   '(("^###\\(#\\)\\([^#].*\\)$" (1 'ess-jb-hide-face t)(2 'ess-jb-h1-face t))
     ("^###\\(##\\)\\([^#].*\\)$" (1 'ess-jb-hide-face t)(2 'ess-jb-h2-face t))
     ("^###\\(###\\)\\([^#].*\\)$" (1 'ess-jb-hide-face t)(2 'ess-jb-h3-face t))
     ("^###\\( .*\\|$\\)" 1 'ess-jb-comment-face t)
     ("^###" "\\*.*?\\*" nil nil (0 'ess-jb-comment-bold-face append))
     ))
```

`

I just setup a new computer and installed the latest EMACS ESS. The code no longer works to organize comments into a hierarchical structure. What do I need to do to regain functionality?

I have tried several manipulations as to where this code is located in my init.el file and I have removed all other code from the init.el file, but this feature still does not work.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/Lindydancer/font-lock-studio ? With this tool you can debug font-lock keywords. In particular, you can check that they are still present when ESS more starts.

Comment: It appears that they are not present once ESS starts. How do I trouble shoot that further?

Comment: I would look into how ESS handles font+lock keywords. Alternatively, define your own ess mode hook and add your keyword there. In that case you should pass `nil` as the mode parameter instead of ess-mode (`nil` stands for the current buffer).